# AngularJS $parse not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand $parse, based on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24parse). But I am having trouble to get my test code working. Am I using $parse service the right way?

The main part of the code is:

```
app.directive('try', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      sayHello: "&hello"
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div style='background:gray;color:white'>Hello I am try: <span ng-transclude></span><div>",
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {
      var getter = $parse($attr.sayHello);
      // var setter = getter.assign;
      $elem.on('click', function() {
        getter($scope);
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

See my code at: http://plnkr.co/edit/lwV5sHGoCf2HtQa3DaVI

Comment: I think that what you are tryring to parse "hello()" is not a valid angular expression.

Comment: It is a function defined in the MainController.  $scope.hello = function() {    alert("hello from main controller");  };

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achive? You want the hello function to be triggered when the user clicks <try> element?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni hmm... I think so

Comment: @Ikahtz Check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/AVvxLR4RcmWhLo8eqYyd?p=preview . I changed the directive scope to be hello: "=sayHello" . It seems to be working a little better

Comment: @ShaiAharoni does it mean that sayHello should be regarded as expression rather than a function?

Comment: @Justin I guess so...

Comment: @ShaiAharoni hmm.. it sounds reasonable to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the $parse method, but this code achives what you are looking for:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AVvxLR4RcmWhLo8eqYyd?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, the `$parse` service is intended to be used outside of an isolate scope.

When you have an isolate scope, like in your directive, you can obtain a reference to the parent scope's function using the `'sayHello': '&'` as proposed in Shai's answer. The `$parse` service might still work as expected even with an isolate scope, if you are able to pass in the parent scope instead of the directive's scope when calling `getter($scope)`, but I haven't tested that.

**Edit:** This is indeed the case - using `getter($scope.$parent)` works fine. When an isolate scope is used in your directive, the `$scope` variable no longer refers to the correct context for the getter function returned by the `$parse` service. Access the correct one by using `$scope.$parent`.

However, if you are avoiding an isolate scope, your approach works well. Try removing the `scope: { ... }` section out of your directive definition entirely and you'll see it works fine. This is handy if you are creating a directive for event binding that might be applied to an element in conjunction with another directive that has an isolate scope, say a `dragenter` directive (which isn't provided by Angular). You couldn't use Shai's method in that case, since the isolate scopes would collide and you'd get an error, but you could use the `$parse` service.

Here's an updated plunker with the `scope` removed from the directive definition: http://plnkr.co/edit/6jIjc8lAK9yjYnwDuHYZ